# Why using Merge node in the activity diagram?

Tags: uml

My question is about the merge node in the UML activity diagram, when and why to use it?

Merge node example:

[image: Link to Merge node example]

Answer (score 1):

A merge node accepts a single token to continue processing. Other nodes need tokens at all incoming edges to start processing. So if a flow is split by a decision you have a single token passing at one side of it. In order to reach the Join at the lower end, you need to collect either flow left and right to collect the single token and pass it on.

N.B.: Activity diagrams have their root in Petri nets. You could consult Wikipedia to see how they work in detail. There also a couple of answers here on SO.